# What can I do if I have 2 equal average?

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing

I have a list of students and some notes, and I have to find the average of each student's grades and show them the following way(if the average is greater than or equal to 6.0):

[student name, average] (in descending order of the average).

I did this, but the problem is that I have 2 equal averages and I can not correspond with the name of the student, he takes my first student with the average '6.0' in both cases.

My lists look like this:

```
info = [['Frank Morgan', '7.89', '3.19', '6.90', '9.90'], ['Jesse Lawrence', '6', '6', '6', '6'], ['Mark Porter', '9.00', '7.87', '9.12', '10.00'], ['Philip Sanchez', '6', '6', '6', '6']]

average= [6.970000000000001, 6.0, 8.9975, 6.0]
```

I want to create the following:

```
result = [['Frank Morgan', 6.970000000000001], ['Jesse Lawrence', 6.0],['Mark Porter', 8.9975], ['Philip Sanchez', 6.0]]
```

I tried in the following way:

```
result = []
for i in average:
    if i >= 6.0:
        result.append([info[average.index(i)][0], i])
print result
```

But I got:

```
result = [['Frank Morgan', 6.970000000000001], ['Jesse Lawrence', 6.0],['Mark Porter', 8.9975], ['Jesse Lawrence', 6.0]]
```

'Jesse Lawrence' instead of 'Philip Sanchez'

Please help me to find another solution for this matching problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do `info[average.index(i)]` then `average.index(i)` will return the first occurrence of `i` in average.

you can use `enumerate()`

```
info = [['Frank Morgan', '7.89', '3.19', '6.90', '9.90'], ['Jesse Lawrence', '6', '6', '6', '6'], ['Mark Porter', '9.00', '7.87', '9.12', '10.00'], ['Philip Sanchez', '6', '6', '6', '6']]
average= [6.970000000000001, 6.0, 8.9975, 6.0]
for idx, value in enumerate(average):
    if value >= 6.0:
        result.append([info[idx])][0], value])
print result
```

or even better - use zip()

```
info = [['Frank Morgan', '7.89', '3.19', '6.90', '9.90'], ['Jesse Lawrence', '6', '6', '6', '6'], ['Mark Porter', '9.00', '7.87', '9.12', '10.00'], ['Philip Sanchez', '6', '6', '6', '6']]
average= [6.970000000000001, 6.0, 8.9975, 6.0]
result = []
for student, value in zip(info, average):
    if value >= 6.0:
        result.append([student[0], value])

print result
```

as a side note - start using python3

Answer (score 0):

With help of `numpy` and [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) you can do it like this:

```
[[k, np.mean(np.array(list(g)[0][1:], dtype='float'))] for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0]), lambda x: x[0])]
```

And get:

```
[['Frank Morgan', 6.970000000000001],
 ['Jesse Lawrence', 6.0],
 ['Mark Porter', 8.9975],
 ['Philip Sanchez', 6.0]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use the numpy